# greet function does not return string value?

Tags: java

```
public class Person {
  String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
        name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing with this code ?

Comment: Please format your code correctly and make your title more specific - we are here to help, not do your work. As for your code, I can't see any issues, the only issue you could have is that you are calling methods without parsing an argument, or not calling your constructor before calling the 'greet' method which would cause 'name' to be null.

Comment: Is that the only code you got?

Comment: The answer would be: Nothing.

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with it? If you have more information, you should include it in your question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in this code, so there's probably something wrong in the way you are trying to call it.

Comment: greet function does not return the string value

Comment: The only problem I can see is that you want to use `return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine..

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
        name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person("Marcx");  // create an object Person
        System.out.println(p.greet("Ankit hacker")); //print the greet message
    }
}
```

Will output: `Hi Marcx, my name is Ankit hacker`

So probably you are calling it in the wrong way

**EDIT**

As Tom precised in the comment, you probably want to change the order of `name` and `yourName`

Comment: And you think this is correct? You created a person `"Marcx"` and said *greet* `"Ankit hacker"` and the output is *"my name is Ankit hacker"*. Don't you think it should be `String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name)`? ;P

Comment: yeah you are probably right... :D

Answer (score 0):

I am able to understand what you are trying to do with this startup level code. You are missing main method here. That's why you are not able to execute it. Try this below code with the main method

```
public class Person 
{
    String name;

    public Person(String personName) 
    {
        name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) 
    {
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Person p = new Person("A");
        System.out.println(p.greet("B"));
    }
}

$ javac Person.java
$ java Person
Hi A, my name is B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Person {
String name;

public Person(String personName) {
    name = personName;
}

public String greet(String yourName) {
    return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person("Person1");
    System.out.print(p1.greet("Person2"));
}
}
```

And The output is:

```
Hi Person1, my name is Person2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with code. It is just that you should have main method as well  :)

Comment: This depends on the used IDE.